# Draw the bars left align keeping the bar width constant?

Tags: jquery, charts, flot, bar-chart

I am getting the bar chart for certain data but I am not getting it as desired using the flot chart library of jQuery.

In case the data is less then the bars are coming with a lot of gap which looks like that some data is missing.

I want the graph to have the bars left align.

What I am getting....

Bars with a lot of gap in between.

What I want...

The Blank space in the center of the bars looks awkward and I want that the bars come left aligned skipping the gap in between keeping the bar width same.

Gap at right side of last bar is not any problem.

I want the bars to be left aligned and keep the space blank that is left in the right side.

Please help me.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: You could add some empty values/bars after your existing ones. This will move existing bars to the left without removing the gaps completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using the parameter axisMargin for the flot library.